# Teradata 'Column Dictioanry Name' and 'Column SQL Name' definitions and differences between them

Tags: teradata

With the following sql query Teradata shows a lot of information about the columns of a table.

```sql
    HELP TABLE Database_Name.Table_Name;
```

Two of them being **Column Dictionary Name** and **Column SQL Name**. So far, they appear to be identical in my query, but I wonder what are the exact definition of each and what are the differences between them.

- [DaveWellman](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/HELP-TABLE-columns-description/td-p/84296) offered some insight on Teradata community.
- For `HELP TABLE` Syntax, please see [Teradata Database SQL Data Definition Language Syntax and Examples](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/eWpPpcMoLGQcZEoyt5AjEg/Y9uvnb13HLL3~p5~_0YK8w), but I didn't find anything really relevant to my question on this page.

Comment: It's related to the session character set, you need to check the *SQL Data Definition Language Detailed Topics* https://docs.teradata.com/reader/EicR5yFgCYpUoOw_lp74Yg/wQ5XU_K4U510J08osFxY4g

Comment: Thanks for the link, [@dnoeth](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/66829/dnoeth). It really answers my question!